# Pandas map on series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a DataFrame with lots of categories, but I'm only trying to use two. I managed to get the result I wanted but it wasn't accepted in my project ('there's better ways of doing it'). Working with 2 columns - Gender (M/F) and Showed (1/0) I'm trying to get out 4 variables: male1, male0, female1, female0 to create bar chart with them.

I was told to use pd.series.map function but I've looked everywhere and can't find a good example on it - also not really sure how to get 4 variables out of it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Give proper examples of what you mean by 4 variables

Comment: The dataframe has columns Gender with Male/Female and Showed with 1 for those who showed up and 0 for those that didn't. Trying to get number of males who showed up, males who didn't show up, females who showed up and females who didn't show up.

Comment: Please post the sample dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Series.map` is unnecessary. You can use `GroupBy` here and output a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['M', 0], ['M', 1], ['M', 1], ['F', 0], ['F', 0], ['F', 1]],
                  columns=['Gender', 'Showed'])

d = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Showed']).size().to_dict()

# {('F', 0): 2, ('F', 1): 1, ('M', 0): 1, ('M', 1): 2}
```

In general, you should avoid creating a variable number of variables. A dictionary allows you to extract values efficiently, e.g. via `d[('F', 0)]` for Female gender and 0 showed.

---

But if you really *must* use `map`, you can use the [`pd.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) version:

```
d = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Showed']).size()

res = df.drop_duplicates()
res['Counts'] = res.set_index(['Gender', 'Showed']).index.map(d.get)

print(res)

  Gender  Showed  Counts
0      M       0       1
1      M       1       2
3      F       0       2
5      F       1       1
```

Comment: That's the problem - I had it working. It wasn't great I just used a 'for' loop and made it work but 'the job is to show you can use built-in functions'. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Coolkidscandie, You should tell your professor / teacher that using built-ins with Pandas is usually inefficient due to the different memory patterns used to store data.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case for `crosstab` (it's a built-in function :D)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['M', 0], ['M', 1], ['M', 1], ['F', 0], ['F', 0], ['F', 1]],
                  columns=['Gender', 'Showed'])

pd.crosstab(df.Gender, df.Showed)
```

#### Output:

```
Showed  0  1
Gender      
F       2  1
M       1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 4 simple lines.

```
male0 = ((df['Gender'] == 'M') & (df['Showed'] == 0)).sum()
female0 = ((df['Gender'] == 'F') & (df['Showed'] == 0)).sum()
male1 = ((df['Gender'] == 'M') & (df['Showed'] == 1)).sum()
female1 = ((df['Gender'] == 'F') & (df['Showed'] == 1)).sum()
```

Using `apply`, since you need two series and not one, you need to use `apply`.

```
male0 = df[['Gender', 'Showed']].apply(lambda row: row['Gender'] == 'M' and row['Showed'] == 0, axis=1).sum() 
female0 = df[['Gender', 'Showed']].apply(lambda row: row['Gender'] == 'F' and row['Showed'] == 0, axis=1).sum() 
male1 = df[['Gender', 'Showed']].apply(lambda row: row['Gender'] == 'M' and row['Showed'] == 1, axis=1).sum() 
female1 = df[['Gender', 'Showed']].apply(lambda row: row['Gender'] == 'F' and row['Showed'] == 1, axis=1).sum()
```

Using `groupby`

```
counts = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Showed']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Comment: Yeah, this one I know... The problem is I'm kind of required to use the map function to show that I'm using few functions. But thanks anyway